# Protracor e2e testing for getting localdata

Tags: angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing

I have dropdowns in the menubar. When I am testing the dropdowns it's working fine. But, when I click on an item in the dropdown, it is not displaying any data related to that item.

**Test :**

```
it('Add Patient', function(){
          ptor = protractor.getInstance();
    var dropdown = element.all(by.css('.dropdown')).get(3);
    var toggle = dropdown.element(by.css('.dropdown-toggle'));
    toggle.click();
    toggle.click();
    ptor.sleep(2000);     
    var list = dropdown.all(by.css('.dropdown-menu li'));
    expect(list.get(1).getText()).toEqual('Patients');
    var test = list.get(1);
    test.click(); 
        });
```

And logs are printing like this.

```
Dropdown Log***** { parentElementArrayFinder: 
   { getWebElements: [Function],
     actionResults_: undefined,
     locator_: { using: 'css selector', value: '.dropdown' },
     click: [Function],
     sendKeys: [Function],
     getTagName: [Function],
     getCssValue: [Function],
     getAttribute: [Function],
     getText: [Function],
     getSize: [Function],
     getLocation: [Function],
     isEnabled: [Function],
     isSelected: [Function],
     submit: [Function],
     clear: [Function],
     isDisplayed: [Function],
     getOuterHtml: [Function],
     getInnerHtml: [Function],
     getId: [Function] },
  elementArrayFinder_: 
   { getWebElements: [Function],
     actionResults_: undefined,
     locator_: { using: 'css selector', value: '.dropdown' },
     click: [Function],
     sendKeys: [Function],
     getTagName: [Function],
     getCssValue: [Function],
     getAttribute: [Function],
     getText: [Function],
     getSize: [Function],
     getLocation: [Function],
     isEnabled: [Function],
     isSelected: [Function],
     submit: [Function],
     clear: [Function],
     isDisplayed: [Function],
     getOuterHtml: [Function],
     getInnerHtml: [Function],
     getId: [Function] },
  click: [Function],
  sendKeys: [Function],
  getTagName: [Function],
  getCssValue: [Function],
  getAttribute: [Function],
  getText: [Function],
  getSize: [Function],
  getLocation: [Function],
  isEnabled: [Function],
  isSelected: [Function],
  submit: [Function],
  clear: [Function],
  isDisplayed: [Function],
  getOuterHtml: [Function],
  getInnerHtml: [Function],
  getId: [Function] }
Toggle Log******** { parentElementArrayFinder: 
   { getWebElements: [Function],
     actionResults_: undefined,
     locator_: { using: 'css selector', value: '.dropdown-toggle' },
     click: [Function],
     sendKeys: [Function],
     getTagName: [Function],
     getCssValue: [Function],
     getAttribute: [Function],
     getText: [Function],
     getSize: [Function],
     getLocation: [Function],
     isEnabled: [Function],
     isSelected: [Function],
     submit: [Function],
     clear: [Function],
     isDisplayed: [Function],
     getOuterHtml: [Function],
     getInnerHtml: [Function],
     getId: [Function] },
  elementArrayFinder_: 
   { getWebElements: [Function],
     actionResults_: undefined,
     locator_: { using: 'css selector', value: '.dropdown-toggle' },
     click: [Function],
     sendKeys: [Function],
     getTagName: [Function],
     getCssValue: [Function],
     getAttribute: [Function],
     getText: [Function],
     getSize: [Function],
     getLocation: [Function],
     isEnabled: [Function],
     isSelected: [Function],
     submit: [Function],
     clear: [Function],
     isDisplayed: [Function],
     getOuterHtml: [Function],
     getInnerHtml: [Function],
     getId: [Function] },
  click: [Function],
  sendKeys: [Function],
  getTagName: [Function],
  getCssValue: [Function],
  getAttribute: [Function],
  getText: [Function],
  getSize: [Function],
  getLocation: [Function],
  isEnabled: [Function],
  isSelected: [Function],
  submit: [Function],
  clear: [Function],
  isDisplayed: [Function],
  getOuterHtml: [Function],
  getInnerHtml: [Function],
  getId: [Function] }
List log***** { getWebElements: [Function],
  actionResults_: undefined,
  locator_: { using: 'css selector', value: '.dropdown-menu li' },
  click: [Function],
  sendKeys: [Function],
  getTagName: [Function],
  getCssValue: [Function],
  getAttribute: [Function],
  getText: [Function],
  getSize: [Function],
  getLocation: [Function],
  isEnabled: [Function],
  isSelected: [Function],
  submit: [Function],
  clear: [Function],
  isDisplayed: [Function],
  getOuterHtml: [Function],
  getInnerHtml: [Function],
  getId: [Function] }
Test log***** { parentElementArrayFinder: 
   { getWebElements: [Function],
     actionResults_: undefined,
     locator_: { using: 'css selector', value: '.dropdown-menu li' },
     click: [Function],
     sendKeys: [Function],
     getTagName: [Function],
     getCssValue: [Function],
     getAttribute: [Function],
     getText: [Function],
     getSize: [Function],
     getLocation: [Function],
     isEnabled: [Function],
     isSelected: [Function],
     submit: [Function],
     clear: [Function],
     isDisplayed: [Function],
     getOuterHtml: [Function],
     getInnerHtml: [Function],
     getId: [Function] },
  elementArrayFinder_: 
   { getWebElements: [Function],
     actionResults_: undefined,
     locator_: { using: 'css selector', value: '.dropdown-menu li' },
     click: [Function],
     sendKeys: [Function],
     getTagName: [Function],
     getCssValue: [Function],
     getAttribute: [Function],
     getText: [Function],
     getSize: [Function],
     getLocation: [Function],
     isEnabled: [Function],
     isSelected: [Function],
     submit: [Function],
     clear: [Function],
     isDisplayed: [Function],
     getOuterHtml: [Function],
     getInnerHtml: [Function],
     getId: [Function] },
  click: [Function],
  sendKeys: [Function],
  getTagName: [Function],
  getCssValue: [Function],
  getAttribute: [Function],
  getText: [Function],
  getSize: [Function],
  getLocation: [Function],
  isEnabled: [Function],
  isSelected: [Function],
  submit: [Function],
  clear: [Function],
  isDisplayed: [Function],
  getOuterHtml: [Function],
  getInnerHtml: [Function],
  getId: [Function] }
```

Comment: Can you console.log dropdown, toggle, and list to confirm they're collecting what you want?

Comment: I am completely new to testing. I tried lot of functions, bue getting same issue                                                                         Message:
     Expected false to be truthy.
   Stacktrace:
     Error: Failed expectation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing Angular is difficult. Don't be down on yourself. :)

Try these two things:

1. Be more specific with your [CSS selectors](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/locators). Add an `#idTag` to make sure you're clicking on the **exact** element you want:
   `element(by.id('idTag')).click();`
2. Write an assertion. Your test isn't testing anything. It is only clicking on a menu item. What should happen when you click? For example, should a new element pop onto the screen?
   `expect(element(by.id('newPatient')).isPresent()).toBe(true);`

Comment: Actually, I want to test a button. But, if I click on menu item it is not displaying that Button below. Then how can I test that button.

Comment: Is the dropdown menu working properly and displaying the button for you to click if you do it on your own, without protractor?

Comment: No problem @NNR, don't forget to mark an answer on here too, ha ha.

Answer (score 0):

To print the values on console, you need to do the following:

```
var dropdown = element.all(by.css('.dropdown')).get(3).getText();
dropdown.then(function(value)
{
  console.log("Dropdown Log*****", value);
});
```

Reason:
**var dropdown** contains a **Promise**. To print the value, you need to extract its value using **.then**
Another way to deal with **Promises** is using **expect** statements

Please let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thank you. I did something wrong in my code, Now i got the answer.